# How to serve html and php from multiple folders under the same host in nginx?

Tags: php, nginx

I want to serve two folders with nginx: a folder with generated html files, and a folder with static html and php scripts, take this folder structure as an example:

```
├─/var/www
│ ├─generated
│ │ ├─index.html
│ │ └─foo.html
│ ├─static
│ │ ├─index.html
│ │ ├─test.html
│ │ ├─phpinfo
│ │ │ └─index.php
```

From the user's perspective it should be one site and nginx should try to serve files in generated folder then files in static folder (and if its a php script, it should be executed). Examples of which URL should map to what files:

```
http://localhost                   -> /var/www/generated/index.html
http://localhost/index.html        -> /var/www/generated/index.html
http://localhost/foo.html          -> /var/www/generated/foo.html
http://localhost/test.html         -> /var/www/static/test.html
http://localhost/phpinfo           -> /var/www/static/phpinfo/index.php
http://localhost/phpinfo/index.php -> /var/www/static/phpinfo/index.php
http://localhost/nonexistent       -> 404 page
also notice that nothing points to the "shadowed" /var/www/static/index.html becuase generated folder takes priority
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```
server {
  server_name localhost;
  listen 80;
  root /var/www
  location ~ \.(php|html)$ {
    try_files = /generated$uri /static$uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass  unix:/run/phpfpm/shared.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
  }
}
```

It mostly works, however /index.html or /index.php doesnt get appended, so these 2 tests fail:

```
http://localhost         -> 403 forbidden (log: directory index of "/var/www/" is forbidden)
http://localhost/phpinfo -> 404 not found (log: open() "/var/www/phpinfo" failed (2: No such file or directory))
```

But a very strange thing is, if I create an empty file at /var/www/index.html, and repeat the failed tests I get different results:

```
http://localhost         -> 200, /var/www/generated/index.html (this is what I want)
http://localhost/phpinfo -> 404 not found (log: "/var/www/phpinfo/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory))
notice that the error message is different for the same phpinfo request, what's going on?
```

Comment: "error message is different for the same phpinfo request" isn't it different because in phpinfo, you say it is index.*php* (not *html*)?

Comment: @Yorik Before and after I made an empty file at /var/www/index.html, I was sending a request to http://localhost/phpinfo. Before that, it tries to open the folder /var/www/phpinfo, but after the new file it tries to look for /var/www/phpinfo/index.html file and I don't understand why creating this new file changed the seemingly unrelated error.
Yes, the file is index.php, but in my request I don't ask for index.html, just the folder name and let Nginx decide what to serve.

Comment: Log files read newest to oldest. I am not up to speed on the server config portion you quote, but it looks like it tried generated first, falls back to static, and then 404. So your log emits phpinfo: 404 and then emits static.:200. ?  Also, should `fastcgi_index index.php;` be outside and before the `location { }` block? Is it reachable in the case of a directory request?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution (for NixOS):

```
root = "/var/www";
extraConfig = ''
  index index.php index.html;
'';
locations = {
  "/".extraConfig = '' 
    rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
    try_files /generated$uri /generated$uri/ /static$uri /static$uri/ =404;
  '';
  "~ \.(php|html)$".extraConfig = ''
    try_files $uri /generated$uri /static$uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:${config.services.phpfpm.pools.shared.socket};
  '';
}
```

This should be in Nginx configuration, but I haven't tested:

```
http {
  root /var/www;
  index index.php index.html;

  location / {
    rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
    try_files /generated$uri /generated$uri/ /static$uri /static$uri/ =404;
  }
  location ~ \.(php|html)$ {
    try_files $uri /generated$uri /static$uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass  unix:/run/phpfpm/shared.sock;
  }
}
```